# HTML unwanted empty lines displayed between nav and header tags

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I have this plain html, which I want to style, without changing HTML, into a decent looking page. However when I started I encountered those empty lines, between my layout tags. The snippet bellow show this for `<nav>` and `<header>` tags. Why is there an empty line between them. I have also tried commenting out the single space, between the tags, but that didn't help ( which makes sense, because single space should not cause an empty line )

```css
html {
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: 'Lato';
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
header {
 background: radial-gradient(
  ellipse at center,
  rgba(192,169,145,1) 0%,
  rgba(192,169,145,1) 59%,
  rgba(168,143,121,1) 100%
 );
}
body > nav > * {
 display: inline-block;
}
 nav ul {
  float:right;
 }
 nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <p class="brand">potato &trade;</p>
        <ul class="nav-primary">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">about</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">features</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item button-cta"><a href="#">buy it now</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <h1 class="header-title">
            "sweet nutritious and delicious"
        </h1>

        <h3 class="header-subtitle">
            The key to happiness is hidden in the Potato &trade;
        </h3>

        <img src="img/potato-header.png" alt="Potato" class="header-potato">
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are dealing with : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: Have you tried to set a height to your elements ? Setting `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` at the beginning of your CSS document ? Inspecting your page to see to what it refers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

there is a  few ways to deal with margins from first and last child collapsing outside the parent container (see link above ): the easiest might be (to avoid margin reset on children):

```
header, nav {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

snippet to test below:

```css
header, nav {
  overflow:hidden;
}

html {
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: 'Lato';
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
header {
 background: radial-gradient(
  ellipse at center,
  rgba(192,169,145,1) 0%,
  rgba(192,169,145,1) 59%,
  rgba(168,143,121,1) 100%
 );
  }

body > nav > * {
 display: inline-block;
}
 nav ul {
  float:right;
 }
 nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <p class="brand">potato &trade;</p>
        <ul class="nav-primary">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">about</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">features</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item button-cta"><a href="#">buy it now</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <h1 class="header-title">
            "sweet nutritious and delicious"
        </h1>

        <h3 class="header-subtitle">
            The key to happiness is hidden in the Potato &trade;
        </h3>

        <img src="img/potato-header.png" alt="Potato" class="header-potato">
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answer, since it solves the problem and contains most information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess that will work, but Is it a good practice? What is the point of using HTML tags, if u start striping all the default styling on everything?

Comment: That's more of a personal preference, I always set both margin and padding to 0 on custom css file, to avoid problems like your current one: Things happening without you wanting them to happen.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: 'Lato';
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
header {
 background: radial-gradient(
  ellipse at center,
  rgba(192,169,145,1) 0%,
  rgba(192,169,145,1) 59%,
  rgba(168,143,121,1) 100%
 );
}
body > nav > * {
 display: inline-block;
}
 nav ul {
  float:right;
 }
 nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  }
nav {
  background: green;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <p class="brand">potato &trade;</p>
        <ul class="nav-primary">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">about</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">features</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item button-cta"><a href="#">buy it now</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <h1 class="header-title">
            "sweet nutritious and delicious"
        </h1>

        <h3 class="header-subtitle">
            The key to happiness is hidden in the Potato &trade;
        </h3>

        <img src="img/potato-header.png" alt="Potato" class="header-potato">
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

h1 in default got margin, i just remove it. Check last line in snippet

Answer (score 1):

Your H1 have margin-top, add:

```
header h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/rrvpwjxh/